# send sms on symfony and api ovh

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a problem when I try to pass my phone numbers in a form to send sms with api ovh, the phone numbers on the outside of the form I can get them back but inside it sends me a null.
Thank you for the help :

```
  public function sendSmsAction(Request $request)
{

            $listphoneNumber = $request->get('telephone');
            var_dump($listphoneNumber); // it returns an array phone numbers

            try{
            $form = $this->createForm(smsFormType::class);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $message = $form->get('message')->getData();
                $smsProvider = $this->get('app.sms.provider');
                var_dump($listphoneNumber); // it returns null
                $smsProvider->sendMessage($message, $listphoneNumber);
            }

        } catch (InvalidParameterException $e) {
            sprintf("Erreur lors de l'envoie de SMS, il faut choisir un utilisateur : %s . Trace : %s", $e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString()
            );

            throw $e;
        }

        return $this->render('CeUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur:sms.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Could you provide us a dump of the variable which is null and a fake dump of what you want to see. I didn't understand the first sentence. You could write it in french in comment only. (Tu peux l'écrire en français en commentaire (uniquement), j'éditerai la question si besoin)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the vardump before creating the form it returns that                  
     array(5) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(10) "06295874664" [2]=> string(10) "07670765317" 
    [3]=> string(10) "0769464938" [4]=> string(10) "06094563664" }

Comment: but inside if                                                                                                                                              
               try{......
                $form = $this->createForm(smsFormType::class);                                      
                      ......                                                                                                             
                 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                  var_dump($listphoneNumber);die(); ===null
                    
                }

Comment: I don't understant "the inside the form" and "outside the form": $request->get('telephone'); is returning this array when form is not submitted, but is returning null when form is submitted ? To avoid this add an hidden input containing listphoneNumbers in your form.

Comment: I just edit my question normally you understand better with the comments, yes exactly you understood well

Comment: Take a look on method and action of your form. After submit the `?question=` in url is certainly no more present.

Comment: Yes I want to have tracks or keywords, I beg the question if it's better to go through the session, 
this is my first app on symfony

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

Controller

```
 public function sendSmsAction(Request $request)
{

    try{

        $form = $this->createForm(smsFormType::class, array('telephone' => $request->get('telephones')));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $message = $form->get('message')->getData();
                $smsProvider = $this->get('app.sms.provider');
                $phoneNumbers=$form->getConfig()->getData();
                $smsProvider->sendMessage($message, $phoneNumbers);
            }


        } catch (InvalidParameterException $e) {
            sprintf("Erreur lors de l'envoie de SMS, il faut choisir un utilisateur : %s . Trace : %s", $e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString()
            );

            throw $e;
        }

        return $this->render('CeUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur:sms.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

formType

```
 class smsFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('telephone', HiddenType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['telephone'],
        ))
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
            'attr' => ['class' => 'tinymce',
                'placeholder' => 'Votre message',

            ],
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true))
        ->add('Envoyer', SubmitType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            )
        ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'telephone' => null
    ));
}
```

}